# Conditional update in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Can I create in `SQLite` a statement like this?

```
update books set
(if number_of_pages > 0 then number_of_pages = number_of_pages - 1)
where book_id = 10
```

Is there a working syntax for this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A `CASE` statement should work with the following syntax:

```
UPDATE
  books
SET number_of_page = CASE WHEN number_of_pages > 0 THEN (number_of_pages - 1) ELSE 0 END
WHERE whatever_condition
```

Answer (score 5):

Isnt that equal to this statement ?

```
update books set number_of_pages = number_of_pages - 1 where number_of_pages>0
```

Edit:

according to new statement :

```
update books set number_of_pages = number_of_pages - 1 where number_of_pages>0 and book_id = 10
```

Comment: @Phoenix Sure is, for this example.

Comment: @Phoenix I extended the statement a little, but think you're right.

Comment: @ It's good solution. I would rather accept the other one because there is more clear semantics (what I want to do) when somebody reads my code. But has your solution some advantage (e.g. in performance)?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to conditionally update some rows and leave others intact, this should do:

```
update books
set number_of_pages = number_of_pages - 1
where number_of_pages > 0 AND book_id = 10
```

---

If you want to update all rows (with `book_id = 10`) to different values, you can use 2 statements with "opposite" conditions. Assuming 0 is the "other" value, that would look like this:

```
update books
set number_of_pages = number_of_pages - 1
where number_of_pages > 0 AND book_id = 10

update books
set number_of_pages = 0
where number_of_pages <= 0 AND book_id = 10
```

Or just use CASE as others have suggested.