# android SQLitedabase update

Tags: android, sqlite

How to write the following command into sqlitedatabase `update()` function ?

```
String query="update " + TABLE_TASKS + " SET " + TASK_LEFT + "=CASE WHEN " + TASK_LEFT + ">= " + left +" THEN " + TASK_LEFT + "+2 ELSE " + TASK_LEFT + " END, " + TASK_RIGHT + "=" + TASK_RIGHT + " +2 WHERE " +TASK_RIGHT +" >= " + right;
```

Basically I want to know how to insert multiple clauses and `WHEN THEN` clauses into `update()` function?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453651/conditional-update-in-sqlite

Comment: i wanted to know how to do that in android.database.sqlite.update() function

Comment: Did u try with execSql - public void execSQL (String sql)

Comment: yes it is working fine with execSQL, the query String I showed is of the execSQL(). I just wanted to know how to use update() function.

Answer (score 0):

The `update` method takes the new values as a `ContentValues` object, which contains only fixed values.
It does not allow reading old values from the database in the same step.

If you want to write SQL that is more complex than `update` allows, you have to use `execSQL` instead.