# SQLite good practices & ContentProvider

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

## Goal

I would like to ask a couple questions regarding an implementation of a solution for an Android app.

## Context

We have a SQlite database for our App. We also use `ContentProvider` to easily manage changes on the database data and get notified when it happens.

The App has an `Activity` that contains a `ViewPager` with 4 `Fragment`. 2 out of those 4 `Fragment` use common data.

## Issue

Let's say we store credit card data of the user. He may have several cards saved in the database, so we need to know which one is *active*.

I could only think of 2 solutions for this.

1. Save it on `Preferences`
2. Add an *active* field in credit card table

An example of the 2nd solution:

```
╔════════════════╦═════════════╦═══════════════╦════════╗
║      name      ║     id      ║ secret_number ║ active ║
╠════════════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════╬════════╣
║ personal visa  ║ 02468024680 ║           659 ║ true   ║
║ company visa   ║ 13579135791 ║           362 ║ false  ║
╚════════════════╩═════════════╩═══════════════╩════════╝
```

I think that the 2nd one is better since the `ContentProvider` will notify our `Fragments` when the *active* card is changed and they will be able to reflect the change in that moment.

## Questions

However, I am not sure if this is within `good practices` since it can lead to problems, such as having multiple rows marked as *active*. Apart from that, I would also like to ask if there is any way to update all rows with one sql statement, I mean, *active* one and set the rest to *false*.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a Q&A platform for programming problems, not a discussion forum. Please read this first: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I found the way to update all rows at once I am going for it.

I just have to use `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END` statement, which I forgot it existed!

Found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453651/conditional-update-in-sqlite)