# If Then Condition of Columns, SQLite3 Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a table `data` in a database `data.sqlite`:

```
'my_path/data.sqlite'

A B
0 0
1 1
0 1
1 0
```

I would like to add a new column to this table, where each value = 1 if A = B, or 0 otherwise.

I can create a new column by doing:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('my_path/data.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("ALTER TABLE data ADD COLUMN Agreement")
conn.commit()

A B Agreement
0 0
1 1
0 1
1 0
```

I then try a conditional statement: where A and B are equal using the `UPDATE SET CASE` function a la [Conditional update in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453651/conditional-update-in-sqlite):

```
cur.execute("UPDATE data"
            "SET Agreement = CASE WHEN A == B THEN 1 ELSE 0 END")
cur.commit()
```

But I keep getting:

```
OperationalError: near "Agreement": syntax error
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well... the start of that string will be `UPDATE dataSET Agreement`... type `"UPDATE data" "SET Agreement"` into your interpreter to see that...

Comment: @JonClements *Facepalm* ... Thanks